# Websocket second message doesn't send?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a websocket where I need to send two messages. It looks like the second message isn't being received. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my code or the websocket itself. I've used the Chrome Advanced Rest Tools Client and was able to send both messages successfully, but I'm not sure why it's not working in my code.

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:15449/');
ws.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('i am open');
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(data1));
  //ws.send(JSON.stringify(data2));
  ws.emit('sendData2');
});
ws.on('sendData2', function sendBar() {
  console.log('testing!!');
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(data2));
});
ws.on('message', function message(msg1, msg1) {
  //the data received is a buffer
  console.log('received:', msg1, msg1);
  ws.close();
  done();
});
```

Is there not a way to distinguish the different data that is being sent in `ws.on('message')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add an if check to make sure i got the first data and then send the second one.

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:15449/');
ws.on('open', function open() {
 console.log('i am open');
 ws.send(JSON.stringify(data1));
});
ws.on('message', function message(msg) {
  if(...) { 
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(data2));
  }
  console.log('received:', msg);
  ws.close();
  done();
});
```